# eforms puts out "0 0 0"

Tags: errors, acrotex

I've just intalled AcroTex, but it doesn't work correctly.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{letter}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[pdftex]{eforms}
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}

\begin{tabular}{rl}
    \checkBox{a}{12pt}{12pt}{a} & hello world! \\
\end{tabular}

\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

Running PDFLaTex puts out a PDF with the following content:

```
0 0 0 hello world!
```

texlive puts out this error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\@eqBC ...@empty \else \HyColor@XZeroOneThreeFour
{#1}{\eq@BC }{}{}\edef \eq...
```

Is my installation corrupt? I'm running TeXLive 2007 that came with the fedora-repositories.

I put the AcroTex files in the `/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/acrotex` and ran:

```
sudo latex /usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/acrotex/acrotex.ins
sudo texhash
```

I have no clue what is wrong here. Any ideas are highly appreciated!

Comment: Regardless of the error, TeXLive 2007 is indeed quite out of date.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). I took the liberty to format your post a little. Please notice that pseoudo-HMTL `<code>` tag does not work here. See [this link for more details on available formatting](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Comment: Your code runs as such for me (MikTeX 2.9) and I get a check box. May be time to update your tex distribution?

Comment: Thanks for your responses!
I now updated to TeX Live 2013/dev. Now it puts out only (without a box): hello world! As usually, any ideas are highly appreciated! @tohecz
The preview showed it correctly with `<code>`-Tag, but wrong without it ... this confused me. Thanks for correcting it though.

Comment: the problem is fixed already (ok, its more like a workaround), just tried out hyperref and TeX Live 2013 and this works too with evince. So it would be nice if you would close this. ... going to register on this site, I really like it ... even though it's a bit too complex / too much blinking and fading ;)